# How to match but exclude the equal sign in the following JavaScript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match the numbers after the `w=` in the following URL:

```
https://im.ages.io/gO3jOkNHieln?cors&w=4000
```

This regex: `(w=)\d{3,4}` matches it but it also matches the `w=`. How to consider it in the regex but not include it in the replacement?

Comment: No lookbehind in JS - just match it and replace with `w=...`.

Comment: Just use a capturing group around the pattern you need to extract: `s.match(/[&?]w=(\d+)/)[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that:

```js
const regex = /w=(\d+)/;
const str = `https://im.ages.io/gO3jOkNHieln?cors&w=4000`;
let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
console.log(m[1])
}
```